# How do I bulk add whitespace to make all images the same aspect ratio?

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation

I need to order prints online, of photos which span almost 20 years of digital photography, and therefore a wide variety of resolutions.

I don't want any cropping when I order them (not 'minimal' cropping, *no* cropping). They are all different aspect ratios, so this is difficult to achieve.

So, I need a tool which will add enough whitespace to certain photos, but leave photos which are already the correct shape alone. So, something which just adds a specific number of pixels to an image won't do (particularly since, as I mentioned, they are all different resolutions).

We're talking about hundreds of images, so I can't do them individually.

I need something for windows, which is free (gratis). I'd prefer offline and open source, but you can't have everything.

Comment: I see imagemagick has a windows binary. Not sure how to use it though...

Answer (score 1):

1. The Print dialogue in windows or illustrator can be used to accomplish this.
   Choose "Print to PDF" and the output can be given to your printers. 
   The common print sizes are available under Media in the print dialogue. If you're getting these mass printed and framed I assume you will use a common size. 
   If you want all your prints to be 5 x 7 with a varying height white border top and bottom (height will vary based on source image)

In Illustrator Print:

Select 5x7 size in the media options, select "fit to page", placement center, do not rotate, ignore artboards. Printer: Adobe PDF.

In Windows Print:

Select 5x7 for paper size, select "Fit picture to frame", full page photo. Printer: Adobe PDF.

*Warning: some say .PDF is not the best file format for large scale photos.*

2. IrfanView is free software that can accomplish this by the batch, with more output options. With IrfanView open select Batch Conversion/Rename and load all your images.

Select Batch Conversion and Advanced Options. Select Resize, Set New Size, Set Width to (for example) 6". Click OK. 
Select Output Format. IrfanView has many. Your printers may prefer .tif or .raw or .jpg, you should check.

Once you select your preferred file type go into regular options and boost the quality up as much as you can while keeping the file sizes reasonably small. Perform the batch process and check output, repeat as necessary.

Bonus: rename them, sequentially, at the same time.

*Warning, up-sizing old, small, low resolution images for printing may produce poor results.*

Comment: a PDF with a single image in it is not bad *per se*, just that its a container format with a JPG in it. The OP should be aware, however, that PDF presets usually have a "downsample when image is above *x* resolution" option enabled. If the option is left alone, then for images larger than about 1500x2100 px, they will be downsampled and the OP should not delete the original source images.